# Why are JLabels being painted over higher components in a JLayeredPane?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jlayeredpane

I have a JLayeredPane that has four layers:

1. JPanel set as a background
2. Grid of JPanels each holding a JLabel
3. Grid of JPanels each holding several JLabels that are only set to visible if the label in the panel below is empty
4. A custom component that is only used to override the paintComponent() method to draw over everything below

For some reason if I change the background colour of the labels in layer 3 and then draw to layer 4, the labels in layer 3 are painted over the graphics painted in level 4.  I have tried to set ignoreRepaint() on various components as well as playing around with the opacity and code structure but all to no avail.
Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

I won't attach the source code because the project is quite large but I've attached an example that runs as a stand alone program and demonstrates my problem when you hit the "add arrow" button.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GraphicsTest {

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Painter extends JComponent {

    public Painter(int x, int y) {
        setBounds(0, 0, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}

private static final int CELL_SIZE = 40;
private static final int NOTE_SIZE = 20;
private JFrame frame;
private static JButton test;
private static JButton clear;
private static JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
private static JPanel back = new JPanel();
private static JPanel[][] cellPanels = new JPanel[10][10];
private static JLabel[][] cells = new JLabel[10][10];
private static JPanel[][] notePanels = new JPanel[10][10];
private static JLabel[][][] notes = new JLabel[10][10][4];
private static Painter painter;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GraphicsTest window = new GraphicsTest();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GraphicsTest() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600, 700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    pane.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);
    pane.setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

    back.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    back.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    pane.add(back, new Integer(100));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            String text = "";
            if ((i % 2) == 1 && (k % 2) == 1) text = (i + k) + "";
            cellPanels[i][k] = new JPanel();
            cellPanels[i][k].setBounds(k * CELL_SIZE, i * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            cellPanels[i][k].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            cellPanels[i][k].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            cells[i][k] = new JLabel(text);
            cells[i][k].setBounds(0, 0, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            cells[i][k].setOpaque(false);
            cellPanels[i][k].add(cells[i][k]);
            pane.add(cellPanels[i][k], new Integer(200));
        }
    }

    boolean display;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0 && (k % 2) == 0) {
                display = true;
            } else {
                display = false;
            }
            notePanels[i][k] = new JPanel();
            notePanels[i][k].setBounds(k * CELL_SIZE, i * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            notePanels[i][k].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            notePanels[i][k].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            notePanels[i][k].setLayout(null);
            for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
                    notes[i][k][(m * 2) + p] = new JLabel(30 + "");
                    notes[i][k][(m * 2) + p].setBounds(m * NOTE_SIZE, p * NOTE_SIZE, NOTE_SIZE, NOTE_SIZE);
                    notes[i][k][(m * 2) + p].setOpaque(true);
                    notePanels[i][k].add(notes[i][k][(m * 2) + p]);
                }
            }
            if (display) {
                notePanels[i][k].setVisible(true);
            } else {
                notePanels[i][k].setVisible(false);
            }
            pane.add(notePanels[i][k], new Integer(300));
        }
    }

    painter = new Painter(500, 500);
    pane.add(painter, new Integer(400));

    test = new JButton("Add Arrow");
    test.setBounds(50, 600, 100, 25);
    test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            highlightNotes();
            Arrow.drawArrow(painter.getGraphics(), 20, 20, 400, 400, 20, 30, 40, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(test);

    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    clear.setBounds(175, 600, 100, 25);
    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            painter.repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(clear);



}

private static void highlightNotes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
                notes[i][k][n].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }
}

static class Arrow {

    public static void drawArrow(Graphics g, int tailx, int taily, int headx, int heady,
            int shaftw, int headw, int headh, Color outline, Color fill) {
        if ((shaftw % 2) == 0) {
            shaftw--;
        }
        if ((headw % 2) == 0) {
            headw--;
        }
        if ((headh % 2) == 0) {
            headh--;
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        double length = Math.sqrt((double) (((headx - tailx) * (headx - tailx))
                + ((heady - taily) * (heady - taily))));
        int tailLength = (int) (length - headw) + 1;
        double theta = Math.atan2(heady - taily, headx - tailx);
        Point point1 = new Point(0, -(shaftw / 2));
        point1 = getTransPoint(point1, theta);
        point1.x += tailx;
        point1.y += taily;
        Point point2 = new Point(tailLength, -(shaftw / 2));
        point2 = getTransPoint(point2, theta);
        point2.x += tailx;
        point2.y += taily;
        Point point3 = new Point(tailLength, -(headw / 2));
        point3 = getTransPoint(point3, theta);
        point3.x += tailx;
        point3.y += taily;
        Point point4 = new Point((int) length, 0);
        point4 = getTransPoint(point4, theta);
        point4.x += tailx;
        point4.y += taily;
        Point point5 = new Point(tailLength, (headw / 2));
        point5 = getTransPoint(point5, theta);
        point5.x += tailx;
        point5.y += taily;
        Point point6 = new Point(tailLength, (shaftw / 2));
        point6 = getTransPoint(point6, theta);
        point6.x += tailx;
        point6.y += taily;
        Point point7 = new Point(0, (shaftw / 2));
        point7 = getTransPoint(point7, theta);
        point7.x += tailx;
        point7.y += taily;
        //Create arrow at tail coordinates passed in
        Polygon arrow = new Polygon();
        arrow.addPoint(point1.x, point1.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point2.x, point2.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point3.x, point3.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point4.x, point4.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point5.x, point5.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point6.x, point6.y);
        arrow.addPoint(point7.x, point7.y);
        //Draw and fill the arrow
        g2.setColor(fill);
        g2.fillPolygon(arrow);
        g2.setColor(outline);
        g2.drawPolygon(arrow);
    }

    private static Point getTransPoint(Point point, double theta) {
        int x = (int) ((point.x * Math.cos(theta)) - (point.y * Math.sin(theta)));
        int y = (int) ((point.y * Math.cos(theta)) + (point.x * Math.sin(theta)));
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `Arrow.drawArrow(painter.getGraphics(), …` That is not how painting works.  Custom painting must be done from within the paintComponent method.  If you want to force a component to redraw itself (and this call its paintComponent method), call `repaint()`.  Component.getGraphics() creates a new off-screen Graphics object whose operations no one will ever see.

Comment: By the way, this is why you should not use a null layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay2pp.png  The characters of my system’s fonts are not the same pixel sizes as the characters in your fonts.  Use standard LayoutManagers and leave JButtons’ sizes alone, so they’ll accommodate whatever font they’re assigned.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, (as you see) I'm new to graphics - considering the arrows generated in the real program (i.e. length, direction) are determined at run time by the user and I can't pass these parameters into the paintComponent(), method how would I give the arrow object to the component's graphics object to paint?

Comment: @VGR I realise null layouts are awful and I usually use GridBagLayout but didn't want to faff around with layouts for a demo

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ .  Store the state necessary to accomplish painting in instance fields, and use those fields’ values when drawing inside the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: @VGR Got it working - thanks for your input.